# how to write strings in reverse with one character spared in python

Tags: python

I know how to write strings in reverse

```py
txt = "Hello World"[::-1]
print(txt)
```

but I don't know how to do it with one character still in the same place
like when I type world it should be wdlro
thanks

Comment: i don't understand your question. what's expected result?

Comment: try this txt[0] +  txt[::-1][:-1].  In single operation i am not sure there is way to do it

Comment: Do you want it with first character only or any other character?

Comment: i want it with any character

Answer (score 1):

Just prepend the first character to the remainder of the string (reversed using slice notation, but stopping just before we reach index 0, which is the first character):

```py
>>> s = "world"
>>> s[0] + s[:0:-1]
'wdlro'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse all the words in the text based on the criteria (skipping first character of each word):

```
txt = "Hello World"
result = []
for word in txt.split():
    result.append(word[0]+word[1:][::-1])
print (result)
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think you can also use `word[1::-1]`.

Comment: `word[1::-1]` selects the second character and the first character only.

Comment: [I want to apologize.](https://youtu.be/kg12uhZu9_o)

Answer (score 0):

```
word = 'w' + "".join(list('world').remove('w'))[::-1]
```

Comment: ```TypeError: can only join an iterable```

Comment: ```"".join([char for char in "world" if char!="w"])[::-1]``` is needed

Answer (score 0):

This is a more generic answer that allows you to pick a random location within the string to hold in the same position:

```
txt = "Hello World"
position = 3
lock_char = txt[position]
new_string = list((txt[:position] + txt[position+1:])[::-1])
new_string.insert(position, lock_char)
listToStr = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in new_string])
print(listToStr)
```

Result: dlrloW oleH

The simple way using only range:

```
txt = "Hello World"
position = 10
[first, lock, last] = txt[:position], txt[position], 
txt[position+1:]
new_string = (first + last)[::-1]
[first, last] = new_string[:position], new_string[position:]
new_txt = first + lock + last
print(new_txt)
```